# unbound prefix with in xml

Tags: android, xml, parsing, layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.zestadz.ads.ZestadzAd android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundColor="#000000" app:textColor="#FFFFFF" app:keywords="Android game" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have an error saying unbound prefix I copy paste this from a http://www.komlimobile.com web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no namespace for `app` declared. I hope that answers the question you've never asked.

Comment: isn't this the name space "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"" ?

Comment: That's for `android` prefix, not `app`.

Comment: sorry I am a noob , how can I fix this error ? what should I change ?

Comment: You need to add `xmlns:app="something"`, but I have no idea what something for this prefix should be.

Answer (score 0):

xmlns:komlimobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ com.company"